# SSIS - XML/XSD Parsing and storing entities with WCF service

Tags: xml, wcf, service, ssis, xsd

We have to develop an SSIS package that loads an Xml file and its XSD file, the package should extract all informations from the XML file and transform all present-entities to their object-representations, this objects are then sent to their corresponding Web service (in our case we have three WCF-services) knowing that some entities should be sent to a particular service and not another.

my questions are :
1. how to transform all entities from XML to their objects-representation ?
2. is the "Web service task" is capable to send complex objects to a WCF service ? if no, what is the alternative?
3. how can I perform the service selection depending on type of data

Thank's in advance

Samir.